# How do you implement the fetch api?

Tags: javascript, fetch, kotlin

I don't understand, how to implement fetch api in kotlin
my code:

```
var smf: dynamic = js("({})")
smf.method = "GET"
smf.mode   = "cors"
smf.cache  = "default"

window.fetch(url, smf)
        .then({response -> {
            console.log("response")
        }})
        .catch({error ->
            console.error("error")
        })
```

And it doesn't work at all. No console messages and any

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that the problem was inside your first lambda:

```
.then({response -> {
    console.log("response")
}})
```

This code doesn't do anything, because it is equivalent to:

```
.then(fun(response: dynamic){
    return {console.log("response")}  // creates a lambda and returns it for no reason
 })
```

**TL;DR** To fix the code remove the second pair of braces:

```
.then {response -> console.log("response")}
```

Comment: Yep, I missed "run" before lambda, so one of solutions is run {console.log("response")}